# React "can't perform state update on unmounted component" with timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timeout, react-hooks

Questions about this warning have been asked and answered countless times on the Internet, yet - maybe actually because of that - I'm having difficulty finding a comment which touches on my own situation.

I'm working on an autosave feature, whereby when you start typing into the component's form it starts a timer. On completion, a) it dispatches an action (which is working fine) and b) it clears the timer state so that next time the user types it knows it can start a new one.

The issue comes when I unmount the component before the timer is complete: when it does expire I get the `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component` warning as I try to clear the timer state.

Now, just about all the solutions I've found online for this suggest I should create an `isMounted` state variable and check it before running the relevant `setAutosave(null)` state call. Except that - as far as I'm aware - the nature of Javascript timers means that the values available to the `setTimeout` callback (or `Promise` callback, for that matter) are those *when the timer was started* - when of course, the component *was* mounted.

Effectively, I'm stuck between a) the autosave feature requiring a state reset if the component *is* mounted, b) React demanding that the state reset cannot occur if the component *isn't* mounted, and c) the timer preventing any checking (that I can think of) of whether the component is or isn't mounted. Any ideas?

```
const { dispatch } = useContext(MyContext)
const [autosave, setAutosave] = useState(null)

const save = () => {
  clearTimeout(autosave) // in case you manually submit the form
  setAutosave(null)
  dispatch({ type: "SAVE" }) // this line works fine
}

const onChange = () => {
  if (!autosave) {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(save, 30000)
    setAutosave(timeoutId)
  }
}

<form onChange={onChange} onSubmit={save}>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure though, Try change your state using `componentWillUnmount` if your component is class-based component and `useEffect` functional components

Comment: Yep, that's how I've tried implementing an `isMounted` flag - but as described, that state isn't accessible to the timeout callback because of how the timeouts work.

Comment: try to set timeout before mounting is being implemented